# Is this ordering of words wrong "make transparent [object]"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, word-order

I was scrolling around and found the post [Long sentence between "make" and adjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/587408/long-sentence-between-make-and-adjective). The OP is concerned that in the following sentence the bolded part is too long as an object (I think), and it makes it hard to read:

> This is needed in order to make **all the editorial processes the
> manuscript will undergo** transparent.

I was thinking of the following alternative:

> This is needed in order to make **transparent** all the editorial processes the
> manuscript will undergo.

I am not very familiar with syntax structures, but I feel that something is wrong with that sentence. I have felt it many times, because in my mother language word ordering within a sentence is more lax than in English. Actually, I think I can spot someone whose English is not the mother tongue exactly by usage of such a sentence. But I don't know why...

What is wrong with it?

Comment: I am not asking how to make the first sentence better, because that's what the other post is about. I'm asking what is wrong with the second one.

Comment: Don't amswer in comments, particularly when a suggestion changes the meaning. If you have an answer, or even the germ of an answer, write an answer.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of the linked question, where answers and comments conclude that both forms are permissible but neither is particularly elegant. If you disagree with the answers there, it's not really OK to post the same question again in the hope of a different answer.

Comment: @Stuart F It is not. The original contains a question, two alternatives, requests a better alternative, and answers have many other alternatives. This contains just the alternative, and requests what is wrong with it. It could have been any other phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with the OP's second sentence? Nothing.

Why does it seem wrong? It violates the guideline:

> Try not to place anything between the verb and the object.

This is ***not*** an unbreakable rule, even though it is occasionally presented as one. In fact, this rule is routinely broken in English when the object is a long phrase.

See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/348146/placing-adverb-between-object-and-verb), which asks whether you can place an adverb between the verb and the object. The answer to that question is the same as for this question: you can if the object is so long that the sentence would be awkward if you placed the object immediately after the verb.